# Let $S$ a subspace and $V$ a vector space. Show that the additive identity of $S$ is the additive identity of $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, alternative-proof, formal-proofs

Working on the book: Robert Messer. "*Linear algebra - The gateway to mathematics*" (p. 55)

> **16**. Suppose $S$ is the subspace of a vector space $V$.
>
> **a**. Show that the additive identity of $S$ is the additive identity of $V$.

This is my attempt to prove it:

- $0$ is the additive identity of $V$ and $0'$ is the additive identity of $S$.

  - Assume $v \in S$
  - $v + 0' = v$ ($0'$ is the additive identity of S)
  - $v + 0 = v$ ($0$ is the additive identity of V)
  - $\forall x(x \in V \to \exists! y(x+y=x))$ (0 is the unique additive identity of $V$)
  - $v \in V \to \exists! y(v+y=v)$
  - $v \in V$ (since S \subseteq V)
  - $\exists! y(v+y=v)$

    - $v+z=v \land \forall z'(z' \in V \land v+z'=z \to z'=z)$
    - $\forall z'(z' \in V \land v+z'=z \to z'=z)$
    - $0 \in V \land v+0=v \to 0=z$
    - $0' \in V \land v+0'=v \to 0'=z$
    - $0=0'$ (by transitivity)
    - $\vdots$

Is my proof skeleton correct ?

Would it suffice to show

- If $0$ is the additive identity of $V$ then $0'$ is the additive identity of $S$ and,
- If $0'$ is the additive identity of $V$ then $0$ is the additive identity of $S$ ?

Would appreciate some insight from a logic point of view.

Comment: We have that the additive identity $0$ in $V$ is unique and because $S$ is a subspace, we know that $0$ is in $S$ and also is a additive identity for $S$. So by uniqueness in $S$, the additive identity is $0$. At least that‘s what I would say.

Comment: Interesting answer, @user768513. Thank you. How do you conclude $0$ is in $S$ ? Knowing $0 \in V$ and $S \subseteq V$, we cannot conclude $0 \in S$. But, perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: Of course it depends on what you call a subspace, but usually this is one of the conditions in the definition of a subvectorspace.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following @user768513. How do you conclude $0 \in S$ ?

Comment: At the very top, it reads that $S$ is a subspace $V$, rather than just a subset, so there are some hypotheses on $S$ coming out of the definition of subspace. What are they in your case?

Comment: @user768513, they are:

- $S$ is non-empty.
- $S$ is closed under addition.
- $S$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: If $S$ is non-empty, there is some $v\in S$. Now we have vector space and the scalar field has a $-1$, which gives, since $S$ is closed under scalar multiplication, $(-1)\cdot v\in S$. Now the letter is just $-v$(the inverse of $v$ in $(V,+)$, since$(v+(-1)\cdot v)=(1\cdot v+(-1)\cdot v)=(1+(-1))v=0).$) and hence, since $S$ is closed under addition, $0=v+(-v)\in S$.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, @user768513. I'm nearly there. The only missing piece for me is: when you say that zero belongs to S and also is an additive identity? Using your reasoning, how do you conclude that it is an additive identity of $S$ ?

Comment: By definition, $0$ being an additive identity in $V$ means $0+v=v+0=v$ for all $v\in V$, so in particular for all $v\in S$, because $S\subseteq V$.  This means $0$ is an additive identity in $S$.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much, @user768513.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My spiel is not too heavy on the logic, but I think it conveys the essential ideas:

Consider:

$\forall v \in V, \; 0_V + v = v + 0_V = v; \tag 1$

now let

$s \in S \subset V; \tag 2$

then

$s \in V, \tag 3$

whence, *via* (1),

$0_V + s = s; \tag 4$

also, by (2),

$0_S + s = s; \tag 5$

combining (4) and (5) we find

$0_V + s = 0_S + s; \tag 6$

we may now write

$(0_V + s) + (-s) = (0_S + s) + (-s), \tag 7$

from which

$0_V + (s + (-s)) = 0_S + (s + (-s)); \tag 8$

now,

$s + (-s) = 0_V, \tag 9$

so (8) becomes

$0_V + 0_V = 0_S + 0_V, \tag{10}$

and thus by virtue of (1),

$0_V = 0_V + 0_V = 0_S + 0_V = 0_S. \tag{11}$

Comment: Spectacular answer. Thank you ! Could you clarify step 5 ? Did you implicitly used $$\forall v \in S, \; 0_S + v = v + 0_S = v$$

Comment: @F.Zer:  you got it right!  That is, $0_S$ is the additive identity of $S$.  By the way, thanks for your kind remarks..

Comment: If you really like my answer, votes and or "acceptance" is always appreciated!

Comment: @F.Zer:  thanks for the "acceptance"!

Comment: You deserve it :-)